# ScrollPane scroll to Actor

Tags: libgdx

I can see on the documentation that the ScrollPane has a scrollTo method:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html

I'm trying to use it to scroll to any new element added inside the scrollpane's actor (Table) without success.
The main table contains nested Tables (4 of them) so the actor can be in any of them. How would you then implement the following method: scrollTo(Actor actor)

That would really help, thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the ScrollPane and its inner tables are not layed out when you call the method. You can force a layout by calling the validate method.